# Convert textual document to tf.data in tensorflow for reading sequentially

Tags: tensorflow, nltk, text-mining, text-classification, tensorflow-datasets

In a textual corpus, there are 50 textual documents that each document approximately is about 80 lines. 
I want to feed my corpus as an input to tensorflow, but I want to batch each document when system read each document? actually same as TfRecord that used for images I want to by using Tf.Data make batch each document in my corpus for reading it sequentially?

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [TextLineDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TextLineDataset) that will contain the lines of your documents:

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt', ...])
```

After you create the dataset, you can split the strings into batches using the `batch` method and other methods of the [Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) class.